# kibana - logstash as window service in window 7

Tags: logstash, apache-commons, kibana, elastic-stack

I installed and configured kibana in my local machine and I am getting event log from 3 different machine.

As log forwarder I am using  nxlog which is lightweight so nice to install on production without affecting performance.

One thing I need is NSSM - the Non-Sucking Service Manager from http://nssm.cc/ which is blocked by MacAfee. I need it to install all component as window service.
Can anybody suggest Other alternative to install kibana - logstash as window service ?

Update - I try to user apache common daemon to install service but service failed to start saying error code 5 which I guess Access denied.

I am using following command to install

```
prunsrv //IS//logstash-shipper --DisplayName="logstash-shipper " --Install="C:\Jitendra\ELK\Apache_Commons_Daemon-1.0.15-windows\prunsrv.exe" --StartMode=exe --StopMode=exe --StartImage="C:\Jitendra\ELK\logstash\logstash-1.5.4\bin\logstash.bat agent -f logstash.conf"  --LogPath="C:\Jitendra\ELK\logstash\logstash-1.5.4\bin" --PidFile="C:\Jitendra\ELK\logstash\logstash-1.5.4\bin\shipper.pid" --StopPath="C:\Jitendra\ELK\logstash\logstash-1.5.4\bin"  --StopImage="shipper-stop.bat"
```

Can anyone used this component ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\installutil.exe" "c:\"(path to bat files)

or

Allow exception in MacAfee for NSSM.exe